# Garbage value encounter in -C

Tags: c

In this code I have got a string input- "WUBABCWUBNAWBWUB".
here i need to remove the word "WUB" and print the remaining.Example: "ABC NAWB";
i have almost solved it but the problem is when i give the input(given above) I get a garbage value at the end.It shows: "ABC NAWB~@".I cant understand whats wrong with the code,please help me to remove those garbage values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[201], original[201];        
    int cnt = 0, i, j = 0;
    int len = strlen(str);

    gets(str);

    for(i = 0; i < len-3; i++) {
        if(str[i] == 'W' && str[i+1] == 'U' && str[i+2] == 'B' && i != len) {
            if(i != 0 && i != len-3) {
                original[cnt] = ' '; //here i changed "WUB" into a blank line
                j++;
                cnt++;
            }

            i = i+2;
        } else {
            original[j] = str[i];
            cnt++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    printf("%c %c\n", original[j], original[j+1]);
    printf("%s", original);
    printf("\n\nj=%d,i=%d,cnt=%d", j, i, cnt);
}
```

Comment: Start with replacing `gets()` with `fgets()`.

Comment: Also, look into `strstr()`

Comment: Try to add a `'\0'` at the end of the new string.

Comment: I still have the the last garbage value left after using fgets

Comment: Besides, why do you have two indices, `j` and `cnt` for the new string?

Comment: I used it as a backup,but later didnt realise that j and cnt values are the same

Comment: I dont have any idea about strstr()

Comment: [Strstr](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm) allows you to search substring in the string

Comment: I made the modification and got the correct result ...`"ABC NAWBT"`

Comment: the correct answer would be ABC NAWB

Comment: Sorry, the `T` is a typo. I get  `"ABC NAWB"`. Note that your code doesn't work if the end of the input string is not equal to `"WUB"`

Comment: does your string always starts with WUB and ends with WUB?

Comment: yes,always 2 @HetalThaker

Comment: ok then it that case, after for loop (where for loop ends and before print statement) just add one more line of code : original [j] = '\0';

Comment: @HetalThaker - better `while(1) { ... }` handle the check for the `'\0'` and end the loop from within. There are no special cases to handle after the loop then.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes agree but then in that case I think one extra condition requires to break the infinte loop.

Comment: Your solution won't work with an input string that doesn't end with "WUB", as the last two chars will never be copied to the output string. That's because your loop is up to i=len-3

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Yes i fixed it and set it to str[i]!='/0';

Answer (score 3):

A few modifications:

- I have added a `'\0'` the end at the new string
- I have modified the code such that it works even if the end is not equal to `WUB` (maybe useless modification)
- I have removed the redundant `j` index
- I have replaced the `gets` function with the more secure `fgets`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[201],original[201];
    fgets(str, 200, stdin);
    int cnt=0,i, len=strlen(str);
    for(i = 0; i <= len-3; i++) {
        if(str[i]=='W' && str[i+1]=='U' && str[i+2]=='B' && i!=len) {
            if(i!=0 && i!=len-3) {
                original[cnt++] = ' '; //here i changed "WUB" into a blank line
            }
            i = i+2;  // to jump over the "WUB" word
        } else {
            original[cnt++] = str[i];
        }
    }
    for (int j = i; j < len; j++) {  // to deal with the case the string doesn't terminate with "WUB"
        original[cnt++] = str[j];
    }
    original[cnt++] = '\0';
    //printf("%c %c\n",original[cnt],original[cnt+1]);
    printf("%s",original);
    //printf("\n\n,i=%d,cnt=%d",i,cnt);
}
```

Comment: @RobertoCaboni It works, thanks to this line: `...original[cnt++] = str[j];...`

Comment: I missed the outer loop. Not that I like the "obscure" `i+2` making the outer loop to skip, but you just imporved OP's code, and it's enough for me. I just suggest adding a comment 1) in the `i+2` line, 2) explaining the outer loop.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are actually a one-dimensional array of characters terminated by a null character '\0'. so in your program original is a character array and once the values are assigned to it, at last '\0' should be there so adding just one line of code may help you get correct output.

```
original[j]='\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys,i've solved the problem.The problem was solved after giving

```
 original[j]='/0';
```

after the loop.I also used the cnt integer to avoid blanks more than once.Here is my new code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
 int main()
 {

char str[201],original[201];
fgets(str,201,stdin);

int cnt=0,i,j=0,len=strlen(str);


for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++){
    if(str[i]=='W' && str[i+1]=='U' && str[i+2]=='B')
    {
        if(i!=0 && i!=len-3&&cnt==0&&j!=0)
         {
           original[j] = ' ';
           cnt++;
           j++;
         }
      i=i+2;
    }
    else
    {

     original[j] = str[i];
     cnt=0;
     j++;
    }

 }
original[j]='\0';
printf("%s",original);
}
```